# Python - what is the difference between these 3 methods of printing variables?

Tags: python, string, variables, printing

I am trying to teach my friend Python and showed him 3 methods of printing variables of different types without the need for converting them to strings first, but he wants to know which one should he use and I don't know as I have not used Python in a long time so hopefully you can help us out:

```
print("There are %d people in total" % num_people)
```

or

```
print("There are", num_people, "people in total")
```

or

```
print("There are {} people in total".format(num_people))
```

I know that the format method can do other, more powerful, string manipulation operations but other then that I am not sure which is the preferred method to use. I don't know why the first method exists as the 2nd seems simpler.

Any thoughts on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to `%` vs. `.format` please see similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format), as others have pointed out.

Regarding

```
print("There are", num_people, "people in total")
```

This is really just a convenience provided by the `print()` function. In stead of printing just one argument, the signature allows for multiple arguments, which are converted to string separately and then joined with one blank (by default) as a separator. This is quite useful for a quick output of several objects, but generally unsuited for generating formatted output. Just printing a decimal number that is given with high precision may produced an output of limited usability. See [the documentation of print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) for more information on its capabilities.

Comment: Thank you, I was mainly concerned with the difference between printing with multiple arguments and formatting so this helped.

Answer (score 2):

The Python style guide recommends using the `format` method. Here is the link to that document: ["PEP 3101"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)